# Show that $C$ is open and closed in $U$

Tags: general-topology

Let $U$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $x_0\in U$.

Let $C = \{ x\in U ~|~ \exists~ \text{a path in}~ U ~\text{from} ~x_0 ~\text{to} ~x\}.$

Show that $C$ is open and closed in $U$.

My Attempt: Since $U$ is connected,then the only sets in $U$ that are open and closed are the empty sets and $U$ itself. Clearly $C\ne \emptyset$ since $x_0\in C$. Furthermore, I have proved in an earlier exercise that open connected set $U$ in the Euclidean space is path-connected. Thus, $U$ is path-connected in this case. And for this reason, we must have that for every $x\in U$, $x\in C$ since $C$ is just the set of all points that have a path in $U$.

Perhaps there's a way this proof can be formalized properly, I have the idea but I can't seem to write it down properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: The proof essentially just boils down to the fact that balls in $R^n$ are convex.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my argument/attempt  for the proof? It doesn't seem very rigorous and I wanna be sure it's actually correct.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in U$ then $B(x,\epsilon) \subset U$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Since the ball is convex, it is path connected by straight lines.

Suppose $x_n \in C$ and $x_n \to x\in U$. For $n$ suitably large we have $x_n \in B(x,\epsilon) $ and by combining the path from $x_0$ to $x_n$ with a straight line from $x_n$ to $x$ shows that $x \in C$ and so $C$ is closed in $U$.

If $x\in C$, then since $B(x,\epsilon) \subset U$ the previous straight line argument shows that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset C$. Hence $C$ is open.